# EXCEL - indexmatch and dynamic range

Tags: excel, indexing

I would like to use index / match formula to find data in another table with **dynamic range** of rows. 
Simple example:

```
Table 1:
 A C G
 - - -
 1 6 5000
 2 4 5003
 3 5 5006
 2 7 5004

Table 2:
J K
_ _
1 =Formula..
2
3
5
```

I would like to return index on column C, where 2 criteria from columns A and G are matched. Formula `=INDEX(C:C; MATCH(J1&5004;A:A&G:G;0))` doesn't work for me, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your criteria?

Comment: I would like to get data from Table 1 - Column C, where 2 criteria have to match, i.e. from Table 1 - Columns A and G have to mach with Column J from Table 2 and certain number inserted in formula. So, Column A from Table 1 have to match with Column J from Table 2 and Column G from Table 1 have to match with specific number manually inserted in formula (5000, 5003,..). When criteria is meet then get value from Column C, Table 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Table 1:
 A C G     **X**
 - - -     **-**
 1 6 5000  **=A1&"#"&G1**
 2 4 5003  **=A2&"#"&G2**
 3 5 5006  **=A3&"#"&G3**
 2 7 5004  **=A3&"#"&G3**

Table 2:
J K
_ _
1 =Formula..
2
3
5
```

Thus, you can use the X as MATCH's parameter (that is a "helper column" means)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you add a helper column in table 1:

```
H
-
=IF(G1 = 5004; A1; "")
```

and doing the match on this helper column, i.e. `=INDEX(C:C; MATCH(J1; H:H; 0))`.

*(for people using English locale, use `,` instead of `;` as the list separator)*

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to do with an array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
={MIN(IF((A:A=$J1)*(G:G=5000),C:C))}
```

Drag down for each row and adjust the static value (5000)